# How to call a method depending on a computed property in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fullcalendar

I am calling **fetchData()** method from computed property. I don't know this is the correct way or not. I have also another dependability in **Watch function**. fetchData() will also call when **expertId** will change.

I can call fetchData() function using watch or computed property it works though I am confused this process is correct or not. **But, the problem is in my Computed property! after fetching data fullCalendar is reloading, and then somehow this.dateInfo is overwriting and, calling computed property again and again. Just like a recursion. Making call continuously.**

```
  import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue";
    import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
    import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
    import deLocale from "@fullcalendar/core/locales/de";

export default {
    components: {
        FullCalendar,
    },
    props: {
        expertId: Number | String,
        leadToOpen: Number | String,
        config: Object,
        defaultView: {
            type: String,
            default: "timeGridWeek",
        },
        header: {
            type: Object,
            default() {
                return {
                    left: "title",
                    center: "timeGridWeek dayGridMonth dayGrid",
                    right: "today prev,next",
                };
            },
        },
        goTo: {
            type: Date,
            default: null,
        },
    },
    watch: {
        expertId(newId, oldId) {
            if (history.pushState) {
                var newurl =
                    window.location.protocol +
                    "//" +
                    window.location.host +
                    window.location.pathname +
                    `?user=${newId}`;
                window.history.pushState({ path: newurl }, "", newurl);
            }
            this.fetchData();
        },
      // dateInfo(){
      //   this.fetchData();
      // }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            events: {
                type: Array,
                default(){
                    return{
                        id: 'a',
                        title: 'my event',
                        start: '2020-10-10'
                    }
                }
            },
            dateInfo: null,
            busy: false,
            displayAppointment: null,
            displayOwner: null,
            eventTypes: [
                { name: "Kundentermin", color: "#32bb60" },
                { name: "Termin bei Lead", color: "#db0630" },
                { name: "Termin ohne Kunde/Lead", color: "#3f888f" },
                { name: "Privater Termin (akzeptiert)", color: "#4682B4" },
                { name: "Privater Termin (offen)", color: "#505050" },
                { name: "Ehemaliger Termin", color: "#cdcdcd" },
            ],
            showEdit: false,
            showInfo: false,
            showModal: false,
            leadId: null,
            locale: "de",
            locales: [deLocale],
            calendarOptions: {
                headerToolbar: this.header,
                plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
                initialView: "timeGridWeek",
                eventClick: this.eventClickHandler,
                events: null,                
                slotMinTime: "07:00:00",
                slotMaxTime: "21:00:00",
                locale: "de",
                locales: [deLocale],
                ref: "calendar",
                eventDisplay: "block",
                displayEventTime: false,
                height: "auto",
                allDaySlot: false,
                buttonText: {
                    dayGrid: "Tag",
                },
                lazyFetching: true,
                datesSet: (dateInfo) => {
                  this.dateInfo = dateInfo;  // using this vale in Computed property
                }
            },

        };
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchData() {
            this.busy = true;
            const response = await axios.get("/api/users/" + this.expertId + "/startTime/" + this.dateInfo.startStr + "/endTime/" + this.dateInfo.endStr);
            this.events = response.data;
            this.calendarOptions.events = response.data;
            this.busy = false;
        },
    },
    computed: {
      myDateInfo: function(){
       let v = this.dateInfo;
       this.fetchData();  // I need to call fetchData(), when this.dateInfo will change.
      },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchData();
        if (this.$props["leadToOpen"]) {
            this.leadId = this.leadToOpen;
            this.showModal = true;
        }
        if (this.goTo) {
            this.$refs.calendar.getApi().gotoDate(this.goTo);
        }
    },

};
```

Comment: This happens when two watched(also inside computed) props change each other.

Comment: I commented out Watch. But, calling happens continuously  from Computed Property.

Comment: Yes, but you use `this.dateInfo` inside myDateInfo so as soon as `this.dateInfo` is changed, it refreshes myDateInfo (calling that method again). Changing property values inside computed is generally bad idea. It is meant as getter. Not a setter.

Comment: So, is it better to use only Watch in this case?

Comment: Yes. Mostly it is the best way.

Comment: Okay. now using watch only. I changed the method name dateInfo(newId, oldId){} in watch. So, now it checks whether dateInfo is changed or not. Works. But, the problem is after first call somehow dateInfo updated though the value is same. I think after loading the fullCalendar again, the dateInfo is overwritten. And calling the watch again and again. Couldn't find the solution how to stop this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227740/discussion-between-abhijit-mondal-abhi-and-bigless).